# Symfony Session Storage Set Option cookie_path

Tags: php, symfony, session, storage

I am changing **cookie_path** option for Session depending on request uri.

*config/framework.yaml*

```
framework:
   session:
      storage_factory_id: session.storage.factory.native
      cookie_path: '/admin'
```

*App/EventSubscriber/SessionSubscriber.php*

```
class SessionSubscriber implements EventSubscriberInterface
{
    private SessionStorageInterface $storage;

    public function __construct(SessionStorageInterface $storage)
    {
        $this->storage = $storage;
    }

    public static function getSubscribedEvents(): array
    {
        return [KernelEvents::REQUEST => ['onKernelRequest']];
    }

    public function onKernelRequest(RequestEvent $event): void
    {
        if (!$event->isMainRequest()) {
            return;
        }

        if (0 !== stripos($event->getRequest()->getRequestUri(), '/user')) {
            return;
        }

        if (!$this->storage instanceof NativeSessionStorage) {
            return;
        }

        $options = ['cookie_path' => '/user'];
        $this->storage->setOptions($options);
    }
}
```

It worked fine on Symfony 4.4, however Symfony 5.4 throws exception that service SessionStorageInterface does not exists and cannot be autowired.

Is there any other way of overriding SessionStorage options besides creating my own StorageFactory?

Answer (score 0):

[The docs](https://symfony.com/doc/5.3/session.html) suggest that you inject the RequestStack instead

Comment: Well options and attributes are two different things. What is more session does not exists onKernelRequest event.

Comment: looks like a known bug https://github.com/symfony/symfony/issues/45200